# Support of Escaping query identifiers

Tags: mysql, escaping, sequelize.js, tablename

I am using Sequelize 2.0.0 in my node project and my dialect is mysql. For now, i am preferring to use raw SQL queries instead of using Sequelize ORM methods.

I am not able to find any example or documentation regarding "How to use Escaping query identifiers with my SQL queries" in Sequelize.

I want to escape quotes in some case while performing insert or update operations.

I want some support like which i found in node-mysql
https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-identifiers

Can you provide me with some short SQL query (either insert or update)
I guess, the Replacements document provided http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/usage#raw-queries is something different which i am not looking for. or i might be wrong. I want to know will replacement solves my escape issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is a PHP function, you can't use it with a JS library.

Sequelize is an ORM, it abstracts the SQL away (and, looking at the documentation, <del>I can't see an API for injecting raw SQL using it</del>). You don't need to manually escape strings before inserting them into SQL because you aren't writing SQL yourself.

---

I've [found the documentation for raw queries](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/usage#raw-queries).

You can see in the documentation that it uses parameterized queries:

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM projects WHERE status = :status ', null, {raw: true}, { status: 'active' }).success(function(projects) {
  console.log(projects)
})
```

These are the preferred way to escape text for SQL (this [also true in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068)).

Comment: Sequelize supports Raw SQL Queries. For some reason, i don't want to use the ORM shorts methods in that case i will write SQL myself.

Comment: Also see some comments i logged under URL https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1132

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in looking for any documentation regarding "How to use Escaping query identifiers with my SQL queries" in Sequelize. Because Sequelize has absolutely nothing to do with [Mysql identifiers.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

So, to format an identifier, you have to enclose in in backticks and double backticks inside.